# Regex matches part of string corresponding values in dataframe python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have 700 SIMILAR strings in pd.dataframe_1 that look something like this:

```
R17_T20I1E7_S1_N001_1598140_20200203_092621_fil.edf
```

I would like to find a part of string, that matches value in columns in another dataframe.

It looks something like this:

```
pd.dataframe_1

   edf

   R17_T20I1E7_S1_N001_1598140_20200203_092621_fil.edf
   R13_IR_T20I1E7_PP3_S1_N001_V005_20190620_11045_fil.edf
   R15_T18I1E7_PP3_S1_N014_V387_SAT_20190904_154855_fil.edf
   R14_T18I1E7_PP3_S1_N016_V084_20190717_172431_fil.edf

pd.dataframe_2

 R             ID      V      S     N 
R17       1598140  
R13                 V005    S1
R15                 V387    S1   N014
R14                 V084    S1   N016
```

I would like to have a result like this:

`pd.dataframe_2`

```
edf1                   
                                                           R             ID      V      S     N 
R17_T20I1E7_S1_N001_1598140_20200203_092621_fil.edf        R17       1598140  
R13_IR_T20I1E7_PP3_S1_N001_V005_20190620_11045_fil.edf     R13                 V005    S1
R15_T18I1E7_PP3_S1_N014_V387_SAT_20190904_154855_fil.edf   R15                 V387    S1   N014
R14_T18I1E7_PP3_S1_N016_V084_20190717_172431_fil.edf       R14                 V084    S1   N016
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I suggest based on this answer [How to merge two CSV files by value in column using pandas PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60943829/how-to-merge-two-csv-files-by-value-in-column-using-pandas-python/60945953#60945953) but instead of taking a match criteria, I filter the dataframe by taking the lines with only the maximum of matches between the two lists of tokens per value of `edf`:

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"edf": ["R17_T20I1E7_S1_N001_1598140_20200203_092621_fil.edf",
   "R13_IR_T20I1E7_PP3_S1_N001_V005_20190620_11045_fil.edf",
   "R15_T18I1E7_PP3_S1_N014_V387_SAT_20190904_154855_fil.edf",
   "R14_T18I1E7_PP3_S1_N016_V084_20190717_172431_fil.edf"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"R": ["R17", "R13", "R15", "R14"],
                    "ID": ["1598140","", "", ""],
                    "V":["", "V005", "V387", "V084"],
                    "S": ["", "S1", "S1", "S1"],
                    "N": ["", "", "N014", "N016"]})

tokenizer = nltk.RegexpTokenizer(r'[a-z-A-Z0-9]+')
# I break down the name in edf
df1["tokens"] = (df1["edf"].apply(tokenizer.tokenize))
# And the same for df2
df2["tokens"] = df2.loc[:,"R"].values + "_" + \
                   df2.loc[:,"ID"].values + "_" + \
               df2.loc[:,"V"].values + "_" +\
               df2.loc[:,"S"].values + "_" +\
               df2.loc[:,"N"].values
df2["tokens"] = (df2["tokens"].apply(tokenizer.tokenize))
# cartesian product

df1["key"] = 1
df2["key"] = 1
df = pd.merge(df1,df2, on = "key")

df['intersection'] =\
    [len(list(set(a).intersection(set(b))))
     for a, b in zip(df.tokens_x,
                     df.tokens_y)]
# take only lines where intersection is max for each edf value (= "best match")
idx = df.groupby(['edf'])['intersection'].transform(max) == df['intersection']
df = df.loc[idx,:]
```

The result is :

```
    edf    R  ...   S     N
0   R17_T20I1E7_S1_N001_1598140_20200203_092621_fi...  R17  ...          
5   R13_IR_T20I1E7_PP3_S1_N001_V005_20190620_11045...  R13  ...  S1      
10  R15_T18I1E7_PP3_S1_N014_V387_SAT_20190904_1548...  R15  ...  S1  N014
15  R14_T18I1E7_PP3_S1_N016_V084_20190717_172431_f...  R14  ...  S1  N016
```